# Synchronize travelers profiles in Sabre

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm looking to find a way to sync travelers' profiles in Sabre.
I could not found any Rest API for this purpose.

Regarding Soap APIs: I found some APIs from Sabre documentation but I'm confused a bit to choose the right one.

Can anyone help me to figure it out which one is the proper Soap API to synchronize the travellers' profiles in Sabre?

I want all my company employees profiles synchronized in sabre. Then I can, later on, add PNR against those employees records in Sabre.

Answer (score 1):

There are not any direct API’s available to synchronize profiles. But there are API’s available which can be used to perform different operations like creating profiles, updating profiles, retrieving profile data, moving profile data to a PNR for booking, searching profiles and so on. This includes not just traveler profiles but other like corporate, group, travel agency and so on.

Here is a link for the same:-
http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/providerdoc/PPP/Sabre_Profiles_Technical_User_Guide.pdf

You can also search by the go to the Sabre developer website and search for Profiles to get a list of all the associated API’s:-

https://developer.sabre.com/search?keywords=profiles

Some of the most common methods are:-

OTA_ProfileCreateRQ – Profile creation

OTA_ProfileModifyRQ – Profile modification

OTA_ReadRQ- Retrieving profile details

OTA_Delete – Profile deletion

EPS_EXT_ProfileToPNRRQ - Allows the user to move profile data into the Sabre Passenger Name Record (PNR).